# Using Laravel Auth Registration to create a Stripe Subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-authorization

The title is pretty self-explanatory. I was able to set up a button that takes an existing user and registers them for a subscription in Stripe - but I can't figure out how to create a new user & register them for a subscription in the same step.

I am using Laravel 5.4, and Cashier 7.0.

Comment: If you are doing anything money related and don't know much about it, hire a professional (for your sake). Question related: share code, I doubt Laravel out of box can do all what you wrote by itself.

Answer (score -1):

The Cashier package provides a nice wrapper for Stripe, I've used it on several projects successfully. Creating a new subscription is trivial once you have a user record created. See the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#creating-subscriptions

Take note, you'll need to run a migration to add some Stripe specific fields to your users table as well as generating a new subscriptions table.